# Can I assign an attribute (or some sort of equivalent) to a Javascript variable? Sample code included

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

(Preface: my code is running JQuery)

I have the following code, which reduces a fraction and then displays the result:

This is the function that simplifies the fraction:

```
function reduce(numerator,denominator){
  var gcd = function gcd(a,b){
    return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
  };
  gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
  if ((denominator/gcd) == 1) {
  return [numerator/gcd];
  } else {return [numerator/gcd +"|"+ denominator/gcd];
  }
}
```

This displays the result - in this case `1|3` - when a span in the HTML body has the class `reducedfraction`:

```
var reducedfraction = reduce(4,12);
$('.reducedfraction').html(reducedfraction );
```

All of the above works just fine.
**Here's the modification I'm trying to make:**

If the fraction cannot be reduced (in other words gcd == 1), a parent span with the class `SimplificationPrompt` would disappear.

I don't believe you can add an attribute to a variable, but I tried in vain anyway because I didn't know what else to do. Here's what I tried:

```
function reduce(numerator,denominator){
  var gcd = function gcd(a,b){
    return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
  };
  gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
  if ((denominator/gcd) == 1) {
  return [numerator/gcd];
  } else {
return [numerator/gcd +"|"+ denominator/gcd];
if ((gcd == 1)){
     $(this).attr({  // THE IDEA HERE IS THAT A GCD OF 1 WOULD FLAG THIS IN SOME WAY (I JUST RANDOMLY CHOSE TITLE)
                "title" : "HideSimplificationPrompt"
            });
    }
      }
    }

$(document).ready(function () { //AND THEN THIS FUNCTION WOULD HIDE THE SPECIFIED PARENT SPAN 
$("[title=HideSimplificationPrompt]").parent(".SimplificationPrompt).hide();
});
```

Newbie here, trying to learn through experimentation like this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you return a string inside an array literal?!

Comment: Return a proper array with numerator and denominator, and then do the formatting (joining by vertical bar) outside of your function.

Comment: Don't do it inside the function. Just check outside of the function whether  the result is the same as the input.

Comment: I'm adressing the line `return [numerator/gcd +"|"+ denominator/gcd]`

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the feedback; I'll have to take a look into that later, but that doesn't appear to be the issue because the code at the top of the screen operates fine. This better illustrates my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/a4s2wgv3/3/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can not complete any logic AFTER a return statement. So your entire condition after `return [numerator/gcd +"|"+ denominator/gcd];` is pointless.You must complete the "hiding" or "showing" of your span tag **before** you `return`.

Secondly, if I understand what you are attempting to do correctly, why don't you just conditionally `hide()` the span iff. there is a gcf of 1?

ie.

```
if(gcd === 1){
  $('.span-to-hide').hide();
}else{
  $('.span-to-hide').show();
}
```

Lastly, the way you are returning your result is unlike anything I've ever seen. Not sure if you're doing that for a reason or not...but consider revising.

**Edit**
I admit that I'm having a little trouble trying to understand what you're trying to do, so I will give up trying to answer this question. But I will add a little nugget that may be of help to you in the future...

**If you're trying to target a specific element** and you have access to the html, it almost always makes sense for you to give that element an `id`. `id` is unique by convention, so no reason to try and target parents...or any other stuff. Target exactly what you need by structuring your html in a way that works easiest for what you're trying to do. You're the developer, you're in the driver seat. Don't make your work more difficult than it needs to be.

**Secondly** to get better quality of answers on SO, you should structure your questions a bit more thoroughly. Include complete examples, such that people can actually execute your code or come somewhere close to being able to replicate your scenario. Anyway, I hope you find your solution, sooner rather than later. Keep coding! It gets easier/harder lol.

Comment: Or `$('.span-to-hide').toggle(gcd === 1);` :)

Comment: These seem like great suggestions, but how do I have this target a specific parent span. Ex: Let's say `reducedfraction` yields a simplified fraction but `reducedfraction2` does not. In this case, I would want to hide this `<span class="SimplificationPrompt"><span class= reducedfraction></span></span>` but not `<span class="SimplificationPrompt"><span class= reducedfraction2></span></span>` Would something like `$(this).parent(".SimplificationPrompt').hide();` work instead of `$('.SimplificationPrompt').hide();`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yeah, I just figure OP is new to programming and wanted to give a non JS specific solution.  But yeah, your solution is more sexy, lol.

Comment: @ElroyJetson I tried it out, but it doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/a4s2wgv3/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That seems like a good suggestion, but it doesn't seem like it would target a parent span. It would hide all spans. This JSFiddle better illustrates what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/a4s2wgv3/3/

Comment: It's understood that you would replace `.span-to-hide` with the class that you're are actually trying to hide. Or perhaps we're having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Snoops This is why it's always a good idea to include the HTML along with questions like this. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix the output code with the computation code. Use

```
function reduce(numerator, denominator) {
  function gcd(a,b) {
    return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
  }
  var divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
  return {
    numerator: numerator/divisor,
    denominator: denominator/divisor,
    isSimplified: divisor == 1
  };
}
```

and

```
function display(element, {numerator, denominator}) {
  var out = numerator + "|" + denominator;
  if (denominator == 1) {
    out = String(numerator);
  }
  element.html(out);
}
```

that you can call as

```
var reducedfraction = reduce(4,12);
display($('.reducedfraction'), reducedfraction);
```

It should be easy to put the code that changes the title attribute of the element if `reducedfraction.isSimplified` is true in the right place in the `display` function.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something - I really appreciate your writing this out - but I don't see how this relates to hiding and showing the parent span function. I'm not trying to hide `<span class="reducedfraction></span>` I'm trying to hid the span that wraps it `<span class="SimplifiedPrompt"></span>`\ (Please see here: jsfiddle.net/a4s2wgv3)

Comment: Sure, just use `element.parent(".SimplificationPrompt")` in the `display` function.